# Custom HTML tag not fired

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

Tag on gtag manager is not fired even if Firing Triggers are matched.
Example can be found below. Does anyone knows the reason?

There are not blocking triggers and everything seem correctly configured.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Tried everything from https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/tag-in-google-tag-manager-is-not-firing/ and tried changing trigger options.

Comment: Can you try to wrap your Custom HTML Code in <script></script>?

Comment: Tried it now. It is not working.

Comment: Ok, other possible reasons: 1) If you have any browser plugins active, which could potentially block tags, then try to deactivate them (e.g. ad blocker plugin; but I don't think this will have an impact). 2) When you are in preview mode: Do you see an event called ""gtm.blacklist" on the left? Other than that: Can you share preview mode link?

Comment: what are you trying it to achieve? add a hidden div to the head or something? Check your tag settings. It might be set to fire once per page and you're looking and events that happen after it fired.

Comment: @Nikola please share a debug preview so we can see how it is set up. Here's the instruction: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en#share

Comment: "what are you trying it to achieve?"
Adding a div is just a test. I am trying to add img for tracking users.
"fire once per page"
this is not checked.

I am not able to share debug view here publicly.

Comment: The issue was related to the delay in loading the tag manager. When we removed the delay everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the presence of **gtm.blocklist** on the website.
Basically the developers of the website could place limitations on what type of tags can be executed on the website. So if the blocklist has "html" then any Custom HTML tag created in GTM will not fire even if the trigger conditions are met.

Remove "html" from the blocklist and it will fire as required.

Supporting google doc : https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/restrict